# Cannot read property 'componentDidLeave' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am using Reactjs to create an app, I am receiving that error in the console

> Cannot read property 'componentDidLeave' of undefined

It is happening when an item is deleted from a collection. And I am not using `componentDidLeave` anywhere, so, whats the problem?

Comment: You're using TransitionGroups right?

Comment: @limelights actually I don't know, but I am using this library with this component http://material-ui.com/#/components/cards